# Having issues capturing rowIndex in column renderer

Tags: extjs4, renderer

I’m attempting to check a box in a grid using the CheckBoxSelectionModel.
As the grid loads data from my store, how do I get the rowIndex of the row being loaded?  I would like to test the value of a particular column dataIndex, and based on the value I would like to select  the box at the beginning of the row.
This code does not work, but this is what I’d like to do:

```
   columns:

            [
                    {dataIndex: 'de_sealed_doc', renderer: function(value,rowIndex,store,record){

                    console.log('rowIndex == '+rowIndex);

                    var sealedDocIndex = this.rowIndex;

                    //var gridModel = grid.getSelectionModel().select(2);

                    grid.getSelectionModel().select(sealedDocIndex);

                    //grid.getSelectionModel().selectAll();

                    console.log('sealedDocIndex --> '+sealedDocIndex);
                    //console.log('gridModel--> '+gridModel);
                    console.log('value--> '+value);



                    },

                    hidden: true},

                    {header: 'Document #', dataIndex: 'de_seqno', width: 100},
                    {header: 'Docket Text', dataIndex: 'docketText', renderer: this.customRenderer, width: 1000},
                    {header: 'Document(s)', dataIndex: 'docsDisplay', width: 500}

            ],
```

Could someone please assist me with this?  If you need to see more of the code, so that it makes more sense, just let me know.

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand your question, is the data that your trying to render as a checkbox not true or false?

Comment: No, but thanks for your response.  I wanted to test the value of a dataIndex, in this case "de_sealed_doc," and if the value was not equal to 'y', I wanted to check the box of row on which the value resides.  @Abdel's solution worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get it working with few modifications to your code. Here are the fixes you require:

1. You need to have the correct [renderer function](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer). Here is an example that will help you get all the data you will need:

   `renderer: function(value,meta,record,rowIndex,colIndex,store,view){
    // code goes here }`
2. Ensure you call the [select](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.selection.CheckboxModel-method-select) method of Selection model correctly. Here is an example:

   `selModel.select(rowIndex,true); // The second param set true is MUST if you need multiselect!`

So, Here is how your code should look like:

```
renderer: function(value,meta,record,rowIndex,colIndex,store,view){     

    if(record.get('de_sealed_doc') == true){  // put your correct condition
        grid.getSelectionModel().select(rowIndex,true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works!  Thank you very much.  If you don't mind me asking, how were you able to arrive at that solution.  Before searching various forums, I read through the Sencha documentation and it's VERY limited.  I only knew that those renderer parameters existed because I looked into the Ext.grid.column.Column.getIndex() function's source code.  Could you recommend any books or sites that could possibly make finding the solution for things like this a little less painful?